# Flutter firestore snapshot always null or empty list

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

i am trying to fetch firestore snapshot but it always return null , i don't know where is the problem ..

[please see the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSFjK.png)

my rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

my code 1:

```
await Firestore.instance.document("myDB/EG/EG/Cairo Governorate").collection("Alexandria Governorate").limit(10).getDocuments().then((snapshot)async{
print(snapshot.documents);//[]
});
```

my code 2:

```
await Firestore.instance.document("myDB/EG/EG/Cairo Governorate/Alexandria Governorate").get().then((snapshot)async{
print(snapshot.data);//null
});
```

**Update:**
[how this document does not exist ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X7Do.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your first bit of code, an empty array means that your query didn't find any documents in the named collection.

In your second bit of code, a `null` for `snapshot.data` means that the documented requested doesn't exist.

In both cases, since we can't see your data and verify that it exists, there's nothing else that can be said.  This has nothing to do with security rules, as your queries would fail completely if they were rejected by rules.  I suspect the names in your code simply don't match what's in your database.

Comment: it exists ... , the names are very equal .. , but there is a note , every document in that collection contains another collections/documents etc ..,
for example (Al Azbakeya) contains (Mansheya) collection .. and (Mansheya) contains documents , etc ...

Comment: Like I said, since we can't see your data, we have no way of verifying this without seeing a screenshot or getting full access to your project.  The API is saying your queries didn't find any documents, and it's not lying.  Also consider that you might be querying a project that's different than the one you're looking at.

Comment: i can't believe this ! , i have another note .. please recheck my question above..

Comment: Notice how "Cairo Governorate" is in italics.  That means it doesn't exist, as the message is telling you.  But it's still visible in the console so you can see its subcollections.

Comment: how can i get data from its sub collections ? , with knowledge i don't know the exact collections names ..

Comment: You have to know the names of the collections.  There are no wildcards or deep queries in Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

In [Firebase docs regarding Delete Douments](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data) there is warning that when you delete document it does not delete its subcollections. This is why those docs are marked with this description. However subcollections should be still available.

In your both samples of code you use "Alexandria Governorate" as document while guessing from the screenshot its a collection.

I do not have playground to test it however it should go like this:

```
await Firestore.instance.collection("myDB/EG/EG/Cairo Governorate/Alexandria Governorate").limit(10).getDocuments().then((snapshot)async{
print(snapshot.documents);//[]
});
```

and like this:

```
await Firestore.instance.document("myDB/EG/EG/Cairo Governorate/Alexandria Governorate/<EXISTING DOCUMENT ID>").get().then((snapshot)async{
print(snapshot.data);//null
});
```

Such queries might be successful if any of documents still exist. As all documents in your screenshots are in Italic font I suppose that only references to some empty subcollection left. So  you will not be able to query anything.

I hope it will help!